# Как вывести определенные данные из mysql таблицы с помощью php?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть mysql таблица вида:

```
post_name | post_excerpt | post_title        |

Название 1| Текст 1      | Уник. заголовок 1 |
Название 2| Текст 2      | Уник. заголовок 2 |
Название 3| Текст 3      | Уник. заголовок 3 |
Название 4| Текст 4      | Уник. заголовок 4 |
Название 5| Текст 5      | Уник. заголовок 5 |
```

Как мне с помощью php вывести на странице данные  "Название 3" и "Текст 3" зная "Уник. заголовок 3"?

Где можно об этом почитать в доступной форме? 
Извините, если объяснил запутано - напишите, постараюсь уточнить, что смогу.
Спасибо.

**UPD:**

Код, решающий задачу:

Код после исполнения выдаёт 
"??????????? ?????????? ??????"
хотя должен 
"Диагностика компьютера онлайн", 
т.е. вместо символов - вопросительные знаки.

С чем это может быть связанно?

Сам код:

```
<?php
$sdd_db_host='localhost';
$sdd_db_name='volodya_wp';
$sdd_db_user='volodya_wp';
$sdd_db_pass='*****';
@mysql_connect($sdd_db_host,$sdd_db_user,$sdd_db_pass);
@mysql_select_db($sdd_db_name);
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_name='online'"));

echo $row['post_title'];

?>
```

Почему-то выдаёт вопросительные знаки вместо символов.

**UPD:** Нашел решение проблемы с вопросительными знаками. Далее рабочий код:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$sdd_db_host='localhost';//Имя хоста
$sdd_db_name='volodya_wp';//Название бд
$sdd_db_user='volodya_wp';//Пользователь
$sdd_db_pass='h6vQjCWpA';//Пароль
@mysql_connect($sdd_db_host,$sdd_db_user,$sdd_db_pass);//Подключение
@mysql_select_db($sdd_db_name);//Выбор базы
mysql_query ("set_client='utf8'");//Следующие 4 строки решают проблему с кодировкой.
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_name='online'"));//Запрос

echo $row['post_title'];//Вывод результата.

?>
Всем кто помог, - большое спасибо.
```

Comment: а что, гугл закрыли?

Comment: Спасибо за ваш компетентный и полный смысла ответ, вам желаю такого же в затруднительной для вас ситуации.

Comment: Ну так каков вопрос, знаете ли. А вопрос ваш компетентностью не блещет. Более того, он свидетельствует о том, что раз вы на такой простейший вопрос самостоятельно  не нашли ответ, то, судя по всему, вам просто лень самому в этом разбираться, и вы предпочли, чтоб за вас это сделал кто-то еще

Comment: Безусловно, вы правы, ещё раз вам спасибо за ещё один дельный комментарий.

Comment: Вот не лень же было человеку писать столько текста, составляя вопрос, вместо того, чтобы прочитать первые три строчки любого мануала.. Зачем же вы трудности-то себе ищете?

Comment: @DreamChild, Не стоит так сразу набрасываться на человека, если он задал вопрос значит есть желание и не лень. + Себе вспомните :) Когда многое не понятное и не знаешь, что искать и нуждаешься в помощи специалистов ;)

Comment: RTFM http://www.php.su/mysql/?commands

Comment: Я не прав, простите меня.

Comment: @volodya_nf, поправил ответ, теперь там есть информация о **Знаках ????**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мда.. Было бы хорошо Вас послать за хорошим учебником.

На самом деле, это самые элементарные вещи, которые делаются примерно так:

```
<?php

$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE post_title='3'"));

echo $row['post_name'];

?>
```

**Объяснение кода:**

1. *mysql_query()* - Вытягиваем с базы данных файлы
2. *mysql_fetch_array()* - Заносим в массив
3. *table* - Ваша таблица

**Знаки ???:**

У Вас проблемы с кодировкой, в начале **php**-файла добавьте такие строки:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251');
```

Либо:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Какой из вариантов поможет точно, не скажу, ибо не знаю какая кодировка в **MySQL**, пробуйте оба, *НО* по очереди :)

**Результат:**

Нам выведет, по вашей таблице указанной в вопросе, `Название 3`

Comment: С удовольствием бы ознакомился с хорошим учебником, и так и сделаю. Просто бывает, к сожалению, что время не терпит. Спасибо большое за объяснение.

Comment: @volodya_nf, всегда пожалуйста) Галочку нажмите возле ответа, и можно еще и на пальчик вверх нажать :D

Comment: Код после исполнения выдаёт 
"??????????? ?????????? ??????"
хотя должен 
"Диагностика компьютера онлайн", 
т.е. вместо символов - вопросительные знаки. 

С чем это может быть связанно?

Сам код:

<?php
$sdd_db_host='localhost';
$sdd_db_name='volodya_wp';
$sdd_db_user='volodya_wp';
$sdd_db_pass='*****';
@mysql_connect($sdd_db_host,$sdd_db_user,$sdd_db_pass);
@mysql_select_db($sdd_db_name);
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_name='online'"));

echo $row['post_title'];

?>

Comment: @volodya_nf, проблема в кодировке.

Comment: Пробовал сохранять в UTF-8 (без BOM) и добавлять header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'), пока безрезультатно.

Comment: Нашел решение. mysql_query ("set_client='utf8'"); Ещё раз большое вам спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table";
if ($res=mysql_query($query){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        echo $row['post_name'].' '.$row['post_excerpt'].' '.$row['post_title'];
    }
}
```

Если вам надо конкретную строку, с id=3, то добавьте в запросу условие - `WHERE id=3`.
Как установить соединение в БД надеюсь знаете

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Barton, Доставила эта строка
>добавьте в запросу условие - WHERE id=3
Тобишь, одну запись выводить в цикле? Логика прощай..

Comment: @lamS не тупи, посмотри историю изменений. Изначально я указал как вывести все записи, а не конкретную, после уже добавил тот коммент... остальное он бы мог додуматься сам уже. В любом случае скрипт отработал бы правльно, хотя и код лишний есть если указать id, не отрицаю

Comment: @Barton, зачем минус поставил?

Comment: if ($res=mysql_query($query) // тупость! Тогда уж mysql_num_rows